# App mobile with social login and login

Tags: 7, services

I have an app (cordova/phonega) and a Drupal 7 site. In Drupal 7 site I have "HybridAuth Social Login" that permit to my users to register and login with FB/G+/other social networks.

Now I want to permit to the app's users to login to my site via social too. Via "service" module I can permit my app's users to use Drupal credential for login, but I want use the social login.

So I want this: 
app's user insert social login in my app, the app call social site and check for login/password. If login/password are correct my app must call Drupal 7 site and login the user. If the user is not a Drupal user, my Drupal site must to create user, too.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have the exact same requirement, please